# Is there any way to get Boolean's string binding rather than its boolean binding in Java

Tags: java

Here's what I need to do:

```
    public void verifyConditionSatisfies( Boolean condition){
  
                if (condition) {
                    System.out.println(condition.toString()+ "satisfies)//This is the part i need to get its String binding, not boolean evaluated version
                }else{
                    System.out.println(condition.toString()+ " does not satisfy)
                }

    }
```

Here's an intended usage:

```
verifyConditionSatisfies(10>9)
```

should evaluate as

```
"10>9 satisfies"
```

Comment: This is not possible. You will have to write some additional code to capture that behavior, perhaps wrap it within your own class.

Comment: Your function is passed a boolean value, i.e. true, not `"10>9"`

Comment: Only the value of arguments are passed. You'd have to pass the string separately.

Comment: What you need to do: understand what you are doing. If you really want to print "10>9" ... then that means that you want to have a system that understands expressions, and syntax. I think you really should step back and do a bit of research on programming languages, what they are, and how they work. And why writing `if( a > b)` in source code is not at all the "starting point" to be able to print `a > b` to some human user (in the sense of deriving the actual condition logic and turning that into a string).

Comment: A boolean value is just true or false.  It does not retain any memory of how the true/false result was retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, getting a boolean expression `10>9` as a String is not possible. Giving the expression as a String `"10>9"` might be easier to do it.

Here is an unorthodox way to do it:

```
public class BooleanEval {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        System.out.println(new BooleanEvaluation("10>9"));
        System.out.println(new BooleanEvaluation("25<3"));
    }

    public static class BooleanEvaluation {
        private static final ScriptEngine javaScriptEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        private String expression;
        private boolean evaluation;

        public BooleanEvaluation(String eval) throws ScriptException {
            this.expression = eval;
            this.evaluation = Boolean.parseBoolean(String.valueOf(javaScriptEngine.eval(expression)));
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            String evalString = evaluation ? "satisfies" : "does not satisfy";
            return expression + " " + evalString;
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
10>9 satisfies
25<3 does not satisfy
```

Comment: Neat answer, but I think you should at least explain **how** this works. And what tradeoffs this solution has.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
  verifyConditionSatisfies(10>9);
```

is effectively evaluated as

```
  Boolean temp = 10 > 9;
  verifyConditionSatisfies(temp);
```

The method is unaware of how its argument was calculated.
The character sequence 1, 0, >, 9 exists only in source code.

So, the answer is "no".

Comment: Well, in software, the answer is mostly "yes". It just takes a ton of work. Just write a small interpreter, that *understands* syntax elements, and so on. Nice newbie exercise. Can be done in a 2, 3 weeks ;-)

Comment: Sure, it's all just ones and zeroes, but I think this falls into the category that "if you have to ask the question then the answer is effectively no".

Comment: See the comment I put below the question ;-)